# Matrix for mirroring about a line

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
 3/5&  -4/5& p& \\ 
 -4/5&  -3/5& q&  \\ 
 0&  0& 1& \\ 
\end{bmatrix}

Which represents a (homogenous) mirroring transformation about this line: $x+2y+2=0$

How would I find p?

The actual value is $-4/5$

Answer (score 0):

Plot the line.  Choose some points that you know where they map to (e.g. (0,0)).  Multiply them by your matrix.  This will give you a system of equations.  Solve for p and q.

By the way, are you working in homogeneous coordinate?  Are your points represented as [a,b,1]^T?

Comment: Yes these are homogenous coordinates